# Why jquery toggle not working in angular code

Tags: jquery

Why does the button not toggle when it's under `<tr ng-repeat="Emp in John track by $index">` ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#tab").hide()
       $("#btn1").click(function () {
            $("#tab").toggle();
        })  })

</script>
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <b>Employee Name</b>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="Emp in John track by $index">
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btn1{{$index}}" value="click" ng-click="toggel($index)" />
                    {{Emp.Name}}
                    <table id="tab{{$index}}">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <b>OrderId</b>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="Joy in Emp.order">
                            <td>
                                {{Joy.OrderId}}

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because your table id is `tab{{$index}}` but your selector is `#tab`.  Change to `#tab1`

Comment: i remove {{$index}} even same problem

Comment: Does the event fire?  (add an alert inside the click())

Answer (score 1):

Since the html elements here are added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('click', '[id^="btn1"]', function(event) {
    $(this).next('table').toggle();
});
```

**EDIT:**

Full code is like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tab").hide();
  $(document).on('click', '[id^="btn1"]', function(event) {
    $(this).next('table').toggle();
  });
});
```